# Scrapy spider not stopping after page ends

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have written a spider in scrapy to scrape a website.everything is working fine except one thing.Once the spider has reached the last page it starts scraping from the last page back to first.
here is my code.
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.http import Request

```
from tutorial.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tutorial"
    allowed_domain = ["jabong.com"]
    start_urls = [
            "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/kurtas-suit-sets/kurtas-kurtis/?page=1"
        ]

    page_index = 1

    def parse(self,response):
        products = response.xpath('//li')
        if products:
            for product in products:
                item = DmozItem()
                item_url = product.xpath('@data-url').extract()
                item_url = "http://www.jabong.com/" + item_url[0] if item_url else ''   
                if item_url:
                        request=Request(url=item_url,callback=self.parse_page2,meta={"item":item},
                                headers={"Accept":
                        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"})
                    request.meta['item'] = item
                    yield request
        else:
            return
        self.page_index += 1
            if self.page_index:
                    yield Request(url="http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/kurtas-suit-sets/kurtas-kurtis/?page=%s" %              (self.page_index),
            headers={"Referer": "http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/kurtas-suit-sets/kurtas-kurtis/",
                 "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
                        callback=self.parse)

    def parse_page2(self, response):
        sizes=[]
            item = response.meta['item']
        item['site_name'] = 'jabong'
        item['site_domain'] = 'http://www.jabong.com'

        name = response.xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "qa-title-product")]/span/text()').extract()
        item['name'] = name[0] if name else ''

        brand = response.xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "qa-prd-brand")]/text()').extract()
        item['brand'] = brand[0] if brand else ''

        desc1 = response.xpath('.//div[contains(@id, "productInfo")]/p/text()').extract()
        desc2 = response.xpath('.//div[contains(@id, "productInfo")]/p/span/text()').extract()
        item['desc'] = desc1[0] if desc1 else desc2[0] if desc2 else ''

        sku = response.xpath('//*[@id="qa-sku"]/text()').extract()
        item['sku'] = sku[0] if sku else '' 

        item['age'] = 'adult'       

        gender = response.xpath('.//a[contains(@id, "qa-breadcrumb2")]/span/text()').extract()
        item['gender'] = gender[0] if gender else ''        

        category = response.xpath('.//a[contains(@id, "qa-breadcrumb3")]/span/text()').extract()
        item['category'] = category[0] if category else ''

        sub_category = response.xpath('.//a[contains(@id, "qa-breadcrumb4")]/span/text()').extract()
        item['sub_category'] = sub_category[0] if sub_category else ''

        size = response.xpath('.//ul[contains(@id, "listProductSizes")]/li/text()').extract()
        item['size'] = sizes
        if size:
            for s in size:
                sizes.append(s.strip())
            item['size'] = sizes


        material = response.xpath('//*[@id="productInfo"]/table/tr/td[contains(text(),"Fabric Details")]/../td[2]/text()').extract()
        if material:
            item['material'] = material[0]
        else:
            material = response.xpath('//*[@id="productInfo"]/table/tr/td[contains(text(),"Fabric")]/../td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['material'] = material[0] if material else ''

        pattern = response.xpath('//*[@id="productInfo"]/table/tr/td[contains(text(),"Pattern")]/../td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['pattern'] = pattern[0] if pattern else '' 

        color = response.xpath('//*[@id="productInfo"]/table/tr/td[contains(text(),"Color")]/../td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['colors'] = color if color else ''     

        style = response.xpath('//*[@id="productInfo"]/table/tr/td[contains(text(),"Style")]/../td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['style'] = style[0] if style else ''

        images = response.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "thumb-slider pos-abs")]/span/@data-image-big').extract()
        item['images'] = images if images else ''

        price1 = response.xpath('.//span[contains(@id, "before_price")]/span[2]/text()').extract()
        item['price'] = {}
        item['price']['mrp'] = price1[0].strip() if price1 else '' 
        item['price']['discount'] = ''
        item['price']['sale'] = ''

        care_tips = response.xpath('//*[@id="productInfo"]/table/tr/td[contains(text(),"Wash Care")]/../td[2]/text()').extract()
        item['care_tips'] = care_tips[0] if care_tips else ''   

        item['url'] = response.url

        item['tags'] = ''
        yield item
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks this website will redirect http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/kurtas-suit-sets/kurtas-kurtis/?page=* to http://www.jabong.com/women/clothing/kurtas-suit-sets/kurtas-kurtis/, expected? If so, I think this is a endless spider according to your code.

Comment: Nope this isint if you test it in postman along with necessary spider it will give results of only that page

Comment: According to my local test, the url will be redirected as I mentioned above. For postman, I'm not familiar with it, you can just ignore my answer and waiting for other answer.